# Wrong result on LeetCode problem due to Variable Scope (probably)

Tags: python, class

So I finished solving this problem on LeetCode : Convert a Decimal number into a Roman Numeral [Convert a Decimal into a Roman Numeral](https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-to-roman/), and the code that i wrote in Python works for the test cases they provide directly from the site, works in VS code, Jupyter Notebooks...

But upon trying to officially submit the code, it gives a wrong answer : [Submit Wrong Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybIxM.png)

After some research, many many errors like these happen because people misuse global class variable like :

```
class DisjointSet:
    set = {}
    lst = []
```

And the good way is to do it like this :

```
class DisjointSet:
    # default constructor, init all member data.
    def __init__(self):
        self.sets = {}     # This is init for each test case.
        self.longest = 0   # This is init for each test case.
```

but the thing is in my code I'm doing something similar and i'm still getting the error:

```
class Solution(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Roman = []     # This is init for each test case.
        self.Declist = []   # This is init for each test case.
   
 def intToRoman(self, num):
        strDec = str(num)
        dico_regular = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
        dico_special = {4: 'IV', 9: 'IX', 40: 'XL', 90: 'XC', 400: 'CD', 900: 'CM'}
        keys = list(dico_regular.keys())
        values = list(dico_regular.values())

        '''This part under is just a way of putting, let's say 3724 in a list [3000, 700, 20, 4]'''
        for v,i in enumerate(strDec[::-1]):
            self.Declist.insert(0, int(i) * (10 ** v))
        
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        for item in self.Declist:
            x = item
            if item in dico_special: 
                self.Roman.append(dico_special[item])
                continue
                
            if item > 1000 :
                self.Roman.append("M"* (item//1000))
                continue

            while x != 0:
                for i in range(1,len(values)):
                    if values[i-1] <= x < values[i]:
                        x -= values[i-1]
                        self.Roman.append(keys[i-1]) 

        return "".join(self.Roman)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: in your code, if item > 1000 you are not updating it to substract 1000 from the result. so none of the conditions in the following while will trigger and you will end in an infinite loop

Comment: why am i getting the error even though I can't find any problems in my code, as shown in the screenshot

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Well my code does work i've tried it bit by bit on paper and on code, but the thing is the problem is not in the code's logic, it's in how I probably mishandled the scope of variable assignment

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Well it is true i'm not updating the value, but the thing is if item is > than 1000, then it can only be 2000, 3000 etc, therefore I only add 'M' to the roman Numeral depending on how many thousands item is (1000 -> M, 2000 -> MM...), and after that i use *continue* which goes directly to the next iteration.

Comment: but @ThierryLathuille believe me I've tried it dozens upon dozens of time and. it works just fine, always return *LVIII*, and it even *passes* the checks for the code on LeetCode, it's just that when i want to *Submit* it, it gives this unexpected result.

Comment: Actually I run the code in my computer and for the number 58 it correctly gives LVIII. Could you put the whole code so we see how you are instantiating the class and calling the function? You don't have to make any __init__ function, just past the code of the function in LeetCode and it should work.

Comment: If they don't rerun the whole code for each test, you just shouldn't have an `__init__` method. Just put the content of `__init__` at the start of your main `intToRoman` method, there is no reason to put them anywhere else anyway. And note that you don't even need to use instance attributes, just use normal local variables.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Ok so the thing is when leetCode verifies an asnwer, it only gives you two information : How many cases does it check on, and how many failed.
In my case, I only passed 1, and failed this one, out of 3997 other ones, but to asnwer that question, no, i don't know exactly how the class was isntantiated.

Comment: So it's probably that the class only gets instantiated once. The first test passed, then the others failed as you kept adding your output to the same list. Just do as I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, don't use self.Roman. Create a variable Roman inside the function that you initialize as empty. you don't need any self, any __init__ or anything else apart from a static function that returns a string

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki and Thierry Lathuille I've tried as you both suggested, i removed the init method, and *Roman* and *Declist* to be local to the intToRoman function, but the code still, when submitted, gives an error on 58

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ThierryLathuille you need to remove the references to self.Declist and self.Roman and make them local variables.

Copy/Paste this code to LeetCode

```
class Solution(object): 
    def intToRoman(self, num):
        Roman = [] 
        Declist = []
        
        strDec = str(num)
        dico_regular = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
        dico_special = {4: 'IV', 9: 'IX', 40: 'XL', 90: 'XC', 400: 'CD', 900: 'CM'}
        keys = list(dico_regular.keys())
        values = list(dico_regular.values())

        '''This part under is just a way of putting, let's say 3724 in a list [3000, 700, 20, 4]'''
        for v,i in enumerate(strDec[::-1]):
            Declist.insert(0, int(i) * (10 ** v))
        
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        for item in Declist:
            x = item
            if item in dico_special: 
                Roman.append(dico_special[item])
                continue
                
            if item > 1000 :
                Roman.append("M"* (item//1000))
                continue

            while x != 0:
                for i in range(1,len(values)):
                    if values[i-1] <= x < values[i]:
                        x -= values[i-1]
                        Roman.append(keys[i-1]) 

        return "".join(Roman)
```

Then you can test that the code works doing:

```
a = Solution()
print(a.intToRoman(58))
```

and it correctly prints `LVIII` for 58

Comment: did exactly as you said, copy-pasted the code you posted in LeetCode, but still, same error. I dont know if you can check them, but here are the submission details : https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/679057283/

Comment: Are you sure? I copy pasted this exact code and it passes the 1st try, but it gets stuck on 1994, but this is a implementation problem about the infinite loop I mentioned before in the comments. You should check your code for the case 1994 https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/679059981/

Comment: Wow you're right!, on 1994 my code got stuck in an inifinite loop, but i fixed it by adding = to > at the line  *if item >= 1000 :*
but still my code didn't submit... still stuck at 58... but i now passed 287 checks out of 3999

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just found out the problem. First of all, I was submitting my answer in LeetCode under **Python** and not **Python3**, which is why I had all those weird errors, and Second of all, my solution had an error in it (Yes, i'm sorry @Thierry Lathuille, you were right in the end..)  which was this line `if item > 1000:` which is supposed to be `if item >= 1000:` (to answer @Sembei Norimaki). So in the end my solution got submitted and alas everything ended well! also big thanks to everyone involved in this thread, you were great help!